# How to update table so there's only 1 value with number 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a table that has the columns user_id, car_id, and selected. A single user can have multiple cars, but can only select to use them 1 at a time. I can update their values using 2 different calls to the db, one to update the selected car to 1, and then 2nd call to update the previously selected car to 0, how would I do this in 1 step?

```
UPDATE cars SET selected = 0 WHERE user_id = <id> AND selected = 1
UPDATE cars SET selected = 1 WHERE user_id = <id> AND car_id = <car_id>
```

is generally what I have right now.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE cars 
    SET selected = 1-selected 
    WHERE user_id = <id> 
    AND (selected = 1 OR car_id = <car_id>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `UPDATE` query with a `CASE` expression to set the value of `selected` according to the `car_id`. For example, to set the selected car to 1 for `user_id = 1`:

```
UPDATE cars
SET selected = CASE WHEN car_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE user_id = 1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=45d8173a67fd326b5e394f2bf5ae80cd)

Comment: Hey this looks like what I want, I was just wondering if the else statement changing everything else to 0 would cause a performance issue, as there's a large number of cars in the table (I do understand that my database for this instance, Postgresql, doesn't update it if the value is the same; but does it still affect performance?)

Comment: @Lego490 as long as a given `user_id` doesn't have a lot of cars, this will be fast as it will only update (as necessary) the cars belonging to that `user_id`. If a given `user_id` can have a lot of cars, then a query with a more restrictive `WHERE` clause (such as draz's or forpas' or Gordon's) might outperform it. This query does have the advantage over draz's or forpas' though in that if a user selects the same car twice in a row it will give the correct result, which those won't.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid any unnecessary updates because only 2 rows must be updated:

- the row where `car_id = <car_id>` must set the column `selected` to `1`
- and the current row with `selected = 1` must be set to `0`.

---

```
UPDATE cars 
SET selected = (car_id = <car_id>)::int
WHERE user_id = <id> AND (car_id = <car_id> OR selected = 1);
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iFXJjfKdz9irxLWeGbpe5z/1).

Answer (score 1):

To handle the case where the user selects that *already selected* car, I would suggest:

```
UPDATE cars 
    SET selected = 1 - selected 
    WHERE user_id = <id> AND
          (selected = 1 OR car_id = <car_id>) AND
          NOT (selected = 1 AND car_id = <car_id>);
```

Note:  Postgres supports a boolean type.  So you might as well use it for a boolean value.  If you did:

```
UPDATE cars 
    SET selected = NOT selected 
    WHERE user_id = <id> AND
          (selected OR car_id = <car_id>) AND
          NOT (selected AND car_id = <car_id>);
```

Comment: Are there any benefits of using a boolean over 0/1 values?

Comment: @Lego490 . . . It is a built-in data type that exactly captures what the data should mean.  It can only take on two values (and `NULL`) so you don't have to worry about bad data.